# Is a homomorphism expected to be a (structure-preserving) map?

Tags: category-theory, terminology, model-theory

Is a homomorphism a special type of morphism, namely a structure-preserving map?

For a morphism (of a category), it is clear that we can't always expect that a morphism is necessarily a (structure-preserving) *map*. It occurred to me that I never saw a definition of a homomorphism (for a specific category) that wasn't a map. On the other hand, the collection of all morphisms between objects $X$ and $Y$ in category $C$ is denoted $\operatorname{hom}_C(X,Y)$, which seems to be a three letter acronym for homomorphism.

Is a homomorphism expected to be a (structure-preserving)  *map*, or could a (structure-preserving) *relation* also be called a homomorphism?

Comment: So you are asking about the conventional use of the word *homomorphism*? The morphism sets are often denoted $\operatorname{Mor}_C(X,Y)$ which avoids the appearance of the word in the context of a general category at all.

Comment: @Christoph Well, let's say the "appropriate" use of the word *homomorphism*, instead of "conventional". It certainly implies "structure-preserving" (even so this is not a well defined notion), I just wonder whether it also implies "map".

Comment: Then this is more of a *soft-question* on *terminology*, maybe change the tags. Sorry my (now deleted) answer didn't help.

Comment: @Christoph Already the information that this is a soft-question would be part of an answer. But I agree that I should add a terminology tag (if there exists one).

Comment: Qiaochu's answer might answer your question:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438344/what-does-homomorphism-require-that-morphism-doesnt

Comment: What does this have to do with model theory?

Comment: @tomasz My basic problem is that no single definition of homomorphism for first-order structures seems to fit for all "applications", contrary to the definition of isomorphism: [Structure (mathematical logic)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_(mathematical_logic)#Homomorphisms_and_embeddings). So I wondered whether I'm at least allowed to assume that a homomorphism will always be a mapping.

Comment: @ThomasKlimpel: Well, first-order structures are sets. Morphisms in concrete categories are function. I don't see how a homomorphism of first order structure could *not* be a function... Anyway, there's been a related question http://math.stackexchange.com/q/423060/30222 .  Shortly speaking, the right definition of morphism in model theory is that of an elementary function, and the category is either the category of models of a fixed theory, or the category of subsets of models, or of a single given model (e.g. small subsets of the monster model).

Answer (score 1):

Let me summarize the information from the comments and links into a concrete answer.

- Yes, a [homomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphism) is expected to be a structure-preserving map. This also applies to homomorphisms of relational structures.
- It is possible to think of the objects in a [concrete category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_category) as sets, and of the morphisms as certain maps between those sets. There are categories which are not *concretizable*, for example the homotopy category of topological spaces.
- The term "homomorphism" predates both the term "morphism" and the creation of category theory. Often now in mathematics people speak of a morphism of rings or groups or ..., i.e. they drop the prefix *homo-*. This influence of the general category-theoretic terminology helps explain how the confusion between morphism and homomorphism could arise.
- In a certain sense, even some mappings like continuous functions between topological spaces should not be called homomorphisms. The continuous functions are the morphisms of the category **Top**, which is known to be *not* regular.

Sorry for not citing with exact references, and for modifying the statements slightly to make them "stronger" than they initially were. One reason why I decided to write an answer is that people seem reluctant to give clear definite answers, and instead suggest that this is a soft question. I prefer clear statements when it comes to terminology, even if actual practice and historical reality might be much more complicated.

---

Let me also add some of my own remarks.

The remark that some authors write $\operatorname{Mor}_C(X,Y)$ instead of $\operatorname{hom}_C(X,Y)$ ignores the fact that important authors like MacLane or Awodey stick with $\operatorname{hom}_C(X,Y)$. They rarely use the word morphism, but use arrow instead when they talk about morphisms which are not necessarily homomorphisms. This is probably a wise choice, as people seem to have a hard time to make a distinction between the words homomorphism and morphism. I guess that's the reason why some authors write $C(X,Y)$ instead of $\operatorname{hom}_C(X,Y)$.

Some commenters questioned the usefulness of considering morphisms between first-order structures which are not functions. Funnily, some moments later they proposed that a certain class of injective partial functions would be "the right definition of morphism in model theory". But an injective partial function is not a function, just like a binary relation which is both left-total and right-total is not a function. Honestly, I don't know whether there exists a "right definition of morphism in model theory" (even assuming that we annotate the predicates as "equality like", "inequality like", "both" or "neither"), and whether this morphism would be a homomorphism.